# Mail Sending Problem

Tags: function

```
  public void Main()
    {
        timer1.Interval = 10000;
        timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(SaatMail);
        timer1.Start();

    }


 public void SaatMail(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{

        timer1.Stop();

        //kayıt yapılan en son değeri dataread yardımıyla çekerek, mail gonder servisine gönderiyor.
        SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection(@"");
        SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("select OtoMailID,Adet,BasTarih,Aciklama,Kime from OtoMail where Sonuc=0 ", baglanti);
        baglanti.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        //komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
        da.SelectCommand = komut;
        DataTable dt=new DataTable();

        da.Fill(dt);


     foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {


        Sayi = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Adet"]);
        Kime = (dr["Kime"].ToString());
        BasTarih = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["BasTarih"]);
        OtoMailID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["OtoMailID"]);
        Aciklama = (dr["Aciklama"].ToString());


            SqlConnection baglanti5 = new SqlConnection(@"");
            SqlCommand ekle = new SqlCommand("update OtoMail set Sonuc=@Sonuc where OtoMailID=@OtoMailID ", baglanti5);
            baglanti5.Open();
            mailgonder(Sayi, Kime, islemdeger, Aciklama);
            ekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sonuc", 1);
            ekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OtoMailID", OtoMailID);
            ekle.ExecuteNonQuery();

            islemdeger = 1;


            baglanti5.Close();
            baglanti5.Dispose();
            ekle.Dispose();

    }
     timer1.Start();

}

 private void mailgonder(int Sayi, string Kime, int islemdeger, string Aciklama)
 {

     MailMessage mvMail = new MailMessage();
     mvMail.To = Kime;
     mvMail.From = "info@info.com";
     mvMail.Body = Aciklama;
     mvMail.Subject = "OTOMATİK BİLGİLENDİRME MAİL";
     SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "mailserver.info.com";

     int i = 0;

     while (i < Sayi)
     {
         SmtpMail.Send(mvMail);
         i++;
     }

 }
```

Above function good working.But, I want to send mail  one by one.For example,I want to send two mail 10-seconds intervals. Above function sending mail ,but continuous.How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Use Sleep function(Pseudo code):

```
 while (i < Sayi)
 {
     SmtpMail.Send(mvMail);
     i++;
     if (i%2) //send two mail wait 10 sec and then restart
       Sleep(10000); 
 }
```

i % 2 means: i mod 2